# Loci question for two lines

Tags: geometry

The two lines are given: $3x+4y+5=0$ and $12x-5y+13=0$. $P$ is equidistant from both.

I use the following formula $$\left| \frac{ap+bq+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|$$ where $p$ and $q$ are the arbitrary coordinates of a point, in our case: $P(x,y)$, so that $p=x$ and $q=y$, to equate the distance from $P$ to one line to that of $P$ to the other. I then square both sides, to make sure that the answer is positive. But I am end up, with an equation that has huge constants and which is not correct.

Comment: Why would you get complicated things ?  Remember that a,b,c are known numbers. So you should be left with a linear equation in p and q. I.e.  the bisector

Comment: Continuing my comment from above, actually 2 bisectors.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks. I got complicated things because I squared both sides

Comment: You couldn't help it.  Your userid says I squared.

Comment: Hahah, exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, the perpendicular distance of the given point $P(x, y)$  from the lines $3x+4y+5=0$ & $12x-5y+13=0$ is equal then using formula for the normal distance  as follows $$\left|\frac{3x+4y+5}{\sqrt{(3)^2+(4)^2}}\right|=\left|\frac{12x-5y+13}{\sqrt{(12)^2+(-5)^2}}\right|$$
$$\left|\frac{3x+4y+5}{5}\right|=\left|\frac{12x-5y+13}{13}\right|$$
$$\frac{3x+4y+5}{5}=\pm \frac{(12x-5y+13)}{13}$$
1. Taking positive sign, we get $$\frac{3x+4y+5}{5}=\frac{(12x-5y+13)}{13}$$
$$21x-77y=0$$ $$\color{red}{3x-11y=0}$$
2. Taking negative sign, we get $$\frac{3x+4y+5}{5}=-\frac{(12x-5y+13)}{13}$$
 $$\color{red}{99x-27y+130=0}$$
Thus there are two loci of the point $P(x, y)$

Comment: No, not at all because $X=-Y\iff -X=Y$

Answer (score 0):

Let Locus of point $P(h,k)\;,$ Then Given Point $P$ is equidistant from these $2$ lines

So Using Perpendicular Distance formula,

We get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{3h+4k+5}{5}\right| = \left|\frac{12h-5k+13}{13}\right|$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{3h+4k+5}{5} = \pm \frac{12h-5k+13}{13}$

Using $\bullet |X| = |Y|\Rightarrow X = \pm Y$

So we get Two  equation in terms of $h$ and $k$

Now Replace $h\rightarrow x$ and $k\rightarrow y.$

Answer (score 0):

Every pair of intersecting straight lines has two bisectors. The square root has two signs.

The two bisectors are ( since normal distances from a point on bisector are equal )

$$ \dfrac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}  = \pm \dfrac{A x+B y+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} $$

In your case

$$(a,b,c,A,B,C)= (3,4,5, 12,-5,13)$$

which simplify very easily as they are Pythagorean triplet numbers.